# SFINAE does not disable one of the functions

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I have a `packaged_task` class which wraps a `Callable` and has `invoke()` functions, one if `Callable` does not take any arguments, and a second one when it does.

I get errors accessing `typename traits::template arg<0>::type` for the second one, even though it should be disabled by `enable_if` SFINAE.

Any idea why I am getting this behavior?

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T, typename Enabler = void>
    struct function_traits;

    template <typename T>
    struct function_traits<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>{}>::type> : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
    {
    };

    template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
    {
        using result_type = ReturnType;
        static constexpr auto n_args = sizeof...(Args);

        template<std::size_t I>
        struct arg { using type = typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Args...>>::type; };

        template<std::size_t I>
        using arg_t = typename arg<I>::type;
    };

    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    struct function_traits<ReturnType(Args...)>
    {
        using result_type = ReturnType;
        static constexpr auto n_args = sizeof...(Args);

        template<std::size_t I>
        struct arg { using type = typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Args...>>::type; };

        template<std::size_t I>
        using arg_t = typename arg<I>::type;
    };
}

template<typename Callable>
class packaged_task
{
public:
    using traits = detail::function_traits<Callable>;

    template<std::size_t n_args = traits::n_args>
    typename std::enable_if<n_args == 0>::type
    invoke()
    {
    }

    template<std::size_t n_args = traits::n_args>
    typename std::enable_if<n_args == 1>::type
    invoke(typename traits::template arg<0>::type val)
    {
    }
};
int main()
{
    packaged_task<void()> task;
}
```

Comment: definition of invoke_helper or the task_result is irrelevant. Updated the code to meet the MVP

Comment: I assume you are doing this as an excercise, anyway some side notes : I would leave a lot of the work to lambda expression (not use class member function specialization), so you get all the benefits of lambda capture too and the final template code is a lot more easy (`result_type` will then be `decltype(fn())` with fn being an instance fn_t the template argument accepting your lambda). (And ofcourse there is already std::packaged_task)

Comment: I find this code is far easier to do if you have access to the types in your `packaged_task` template like `template<class R, class...Args>class packaged_task<R(Args...)>`.  Then your invoke "SFINAE" stuff sort of becomes trivial to write - it is just `R invoke(Args...)`.  You aren't fighting against the language nearly as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to check the validity of templates, even before instantiation. To delay this, you have to make your code dependent on template parameters. The problem is here:

```cpp
// OK, delay validity check by making n_args depend on traits::n_args,
//     which depends on the template parameter of the enclosing template
template<std::size_t n_args = traits::n_args>
// OK, this will do SFINAE based on the n_args template parameter to this function
typename std::enable_if<n_args == 1>::type
// ILL-FORMED!!, validity of arg<0> is checked BEFORE instantiation of this
//               member function template
invoke(typename traits::template arg<0>::type val) { }
```

When the `packaged_task` class template is instantiated, `traits` becomes known, and this means that `traits::arg<0>` can also be diagnosed. Validity checks are then performed before you ever call the `invoke` function, and your code fails to compile.

### Dirty Solution

To fix this, you would have to make `arg<0>` somehow depend on `n_args`:

```cpp
template<std::size_t n_args = traits::n_args>
typename std::enable_if<n_args == 1>::type
invoke(typename traits::template arg<0 * n_args>::type val) { }
```

By using multiplication with zero in `0 * n_args`, the expression becomes dependent on the template parameter `n_args`, and the validity check is delayed until instantiation of the function template. The result remains zero.

However, this solution puts faith into the compiler not diagnosing `0 * n_args` as zero. The code is arguably still ill-formed, no diagnostic required. It works with every major compiler, but isn't very idiomatic, and probably incorrect.

### Clean Solution

```cpp
// common base class for 0 args and 1 args which gets the traits
// of the function
template<typename Callable>
struct packaged_task_impl_base {
    using traits = detail::function_traits<Callable>;
};

// partially specialized class template
template<typename Callable, std::size_t n_args>
struct packaged_task_impl;

// partial specialization for 0 args
template<typename Callable>
struct packaged_task_impl<Callable, 0>
  : packaged_task_impl_base<Callable>
{
    void invoke() { /* ... */ }
};

// partial specialization for 1 arg
template<typename Callable>
struct packaged_task_impl<Callable, 1>
  : packaged_task_impl_base<Callable>
{
    void invoke() { /* ... */ }
};

// wrapper which doesn't expose n_args in its template-head
template<typename Callable>
struct packaged_task
  : private packaged_task_impl<Callable, detail::function_traits<Callable>::n_args>
{
    using traits = typename packaged_task_impl<Callable,
        detail::function_traits<Callable>::n_args>::traits;
    // other stuff which doesn't depend on n_args here ...
};
```

This solution may seem lengthy at first, but you can at least remove `packaged_task_impl_base` if you feel like you can just copy and paste its contents into each partial specialization of `packaged_task_impl`.

It also has the advantage that `invoke()` is a regular member function, and last but not least, it's definitely not relying on tricks where your program is still arguably ill-formed.

Comment: That's actually pretty cool, I always though once you have a dependent type inside member function template, the whole thing is delayed.

Comment: I really like your Clean solution. Initially I though about separating it into partial specializations before knowing what the problem was, but wondered if it would be clean enough to be easily maintainable but this looks neat.

Comment: I'd put `invoke()` and `invoke(one arg)` into a CRTP based base class myself instead - the body of `invoke` can get at the full `packaged_task` type and use it.